# Does anyone knows how can I install the gradle experimental plugin offline?

Tags: windows, android-studio-2.0, gradle-experimental

I have the following files:

`gradle-experimental-0.7.0-javadoc.jar
 gradle-experimental-0.7.0-sources.jar
 gradle-experimental-0.7.0.jar
 gradle-experimental-0.7.0.pom`

But I have no idea what to do with them. I want to work with Android Studio and android-ndk. But the PC I'm using for coding has no internet connection so I can't install it automaticaly from the gradle repositories.

Comment: You can see this article:
[Android Studio: Add jar as library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: @M.hsin, I don't think that's what I'm looking for. But thanks anyway.